# Diff-in-Diff: Time-varying treatment and Treatment affects Outcome

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, difference-in-difference

I would like help with the following question. I have searched the internet and I can't come to a definite DiD setup. I appreciate any help or thoughts that you might want to share.

**My setting/dataset is as follows**: I have a panel dataset from a review platform. On this platform, authors (independent consumers) write reviews about a company. The dataset spans the time period 2004-2018, and covers 1200 firms with firm-level data for each quarter. For each firm, I have multiple (or 1) individual reviews written by the indepedent consumers. As such, one firm-quarter has multiple individual level observations. When a company hasn't been reviewed by an author more than 30 days, the company is classified as "undercovered" by the platform and any review that is written on an "undercovered" company is eligible for a fixed payment. This fixed payment is paid to the consumer who writes the first subsequent review starting from when the company became eligble. When a company has been reviewed within the last 30 days, a review is not eligible for a fixed payment. As such, a company can one day be eligible for a fixed payment, because it is undercovered, and not eligible 2 days later, because 2 reviews came out. This fixed payment structure has been introduced in 2012. Thus, before January 1st, 2012, companies could still be "undercovered", but authors didn't get any fixed payment for writing an article on this company.

**My goal**: After the fixed payment structure has been introduced, have more reviews been written on firms that are eligble for the fixed payment compared to the period before the introduction of this structure? I.e. was the fixed payment structure successful?

I have the following regression in mind:

$Y_{it} = \beta_{1}\text{Treat}_{i} + \beta_{2}\text{Post}_{t} + \beta_{3}\text{Treat}_{i}\times\text{Post}_{t} + \text{Firm controls}_{it} + \text{Firm FE}_{i} + \text{Time FE}_{t} + \epsilon$

- $Y$ is defined on the firm-quarter level: the number of reviews by firm-quarter
- $\text{Treat}$ is defined on the individual level: a review is either eligible for fixed payment or not. In the pre-period, I am still able to define this variable, and use it to compare pre and post treatment groups.
- $\text{Post}$ is defined on the time level: 1 if after January 1st, 2012, 0 otherwise.
- $\text{Firm FE}_{i}$ is defined on the company level.
- $\text{Time FE}_{t}$ is defined on the time level. I am aware that $\text{Post}$ is dropped when these are included.

**My questions**:

- How do I aggregate my treatment variable to the firm-quarter level s.t. I can run this test? I want to run it by firm-quarter, since I want to include firm-quarter controls and quarter fixed effects. My idea is to count the number of days by firm-quarter that a review would be eligible for the fixed payment, and set $\text{Treat}$ to 1 if this number of days > 90% (arbitrary) of the total number of days for the firm-quarter.
  *Note: If it is not necessary to run this on the firm-quarter level, I would also be interested. I thought about aggregating to a two period setting: pre and post (like Betrand et al. 2004 suggest).*
- How do I make sure my test is valid when my treatment variable affects the subsequent outcome (a review is eligible when the number of reviews is low)? I have thought about lagging the treatment by one firm-quarter.

Thanks a lot for your time, it is truly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to CV! First, what is $\alpha_{it}$? Is it your 'global intercept' or a firm-level fixed effect? If it is your intercept, you can safely drop it. Second, the firm-level control vector should be $i$- and $t$-subscripted. If the controls don't vary over time, then the firm fixed effects will absorb them.

Comment: Also, why do you define your treatment group by the number of days a firm was eligible for a review? In my first reading, I assumed your treatment group is comprised of all firms eligible for the fixed payment structure, which was put in place after 2012. Is this a correct reading of your question?

Comment: 1. $\alpa_{it}$ is indeed an intercept. I will drop it!
2. The firm-level controls are adjusted to reflect indeed that they vary over time
3. The treatment group varies over time: one day a review of a firm can be eligible for a fixed payment, the next day it can't because a review has come out.

Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: So you suspect post-implementation of the fixed payment policy, firms will be incentivized to conduct more reviews *after* the 30-day period? And when you say treatment is at the *individual level*, you mean the firm level, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify in the post, but this is data from a review platform. Authors on this platform are incentivized to review companies that are undercovered with a fixed payment (instead of only a payment per click) after january 1st, 2018. I will add a section to the post

Comment: I find it difficult to pinpoint at which level the treatment is exactly: if a review comes out on April 1st, 2014 for Amazon (and the one before that came out on January 10th, 2014) it is "treated" because the author of that article is eligble for a fixed payment. If then a review comes out on April 12th, 2014 for Amazon, this review is no longer "treated" since only 11 days passed between the two reviews. on May 2nd, 2014, if no reviews come out between, Amazon is "treated" again: any review that comes out now is eligible for a fixed payment. Hope this clarifies!